# Is there a way to expose a non-contiguous subset of an array, as a single array?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

In my project, I have a class that is analogous to the following:

```
public class Vertices
{
    float[] vertexData1;
    int   vertexData1Offset;

    float[] vertexData2;
    int   vertexData2Offset;

    float[] vertexData3;
    int   vertexData3Offset;

    float[] vertexBuffer;

    int vertexCount;
    int vertexStride;

    public void Update()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++)
        {
            vertexBuffer[(i * vertexStride) + vertexData1Offset] = vertexData1[i];
            vertexBuffer[(i * vertexStride) + vertexData2Offset] = vertexData2[i];
            vertexBuffer[(i * vertexStride) + vertexData3Offset] = vertexData3[i];
        }
    }
}
```

That is, I have an array (*vertexBuffer*), and this array is a combination of another set of arrays (*vertexData1...*). Only the way the arrays are combined, each of the 'component arrays' has its elements spread equally throughout the 'main array', all jumbled up, as opposed to each array being concatenated sequentially.

**I want to know if there is a way to expose these arrays (e.g. some way to subclass Array) (*vertexData1...*) in such a way as the consumer of this class could access them as if they were regular arrays with contiguous elements** (including copying to and from), but behind the scenes, the object would really be distributing these elements throughout *vertexBuffer*, removing the need for the Update() method and the duplicated data.

**Is this possible in C#?**

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use an indexer. Something like:

```
public class Vertices
{
    float[] vertexData1;
    int   vertexData1Offset;

    float[] vertexData2;
    int   vertexData2Offset;

    float[] vertexData3;
    int   vertexData3Offset;

    private float[] GetArrayForIndex(int index) {
      switch (index / vertexStride) {
        case 0: return verdexData1;
        case 1: return vertedData2;
        case 2: return vertexData3;
        default: throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
      }
    }

    public float vertexBuffer[int index] {
      get {
        return GetArrayForIndex(index)[index % vertexStride];
      }
      set {
        GetArrayForIndex(index)[index % vertexStride] = value;
      }
    }

    int vertexStride;

}
```

I'm not sure how you want to arrange the data in the indexer. You may want to swap the use of `/` and `%` depending on whether you want the arrays after each other or interleaved.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement indexer this[int index] and provide your own functionality in it:

```
public class Vertices
{
  public float this[int index]
  {
    get
    {
      // do your stuff here
    }
    set
    {
      // do your stuff here
    }
  }
}
```